# A high-level reason that $u \cdot (v \times w) = (u \times v) \cdot w$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, cross-product

I can do the algebra to show that for $u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, this identity is true:

$$u \cdot (v \times w) = (u \times v) \cdot w$$

But is there a more high-level reason? I didn't expect the cross and dot product to be connected in this surprising way.

Comment: The absolute value of the product $u·(v\times w)$ is the volume of the parallelepiped determined by the three vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$u \cdot (v \times w) = \det(u, v, w) $$

where (u, v, w) means the 3x3 matrix whose columns are $u$, $v$, and $w$ respectively, and thus the triple product satisfies all of the algebraic identities that determinants do.

(alternatively, $(u,v,w)$ can mean the matrix whose rows are $u$, $v$, and $w$, if you prefer to think of vectors as row vectors)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The volume of the parallelepipid is equal to the scalar triple product. Consider the geometric definitions of the cross-product and inner-product to see this.

Answer (score 2):

$u \times v$ can be *defined* as the vector that makes

$$\langle w, u \times v \rangle=\det(w,u,v) \quad  \forall w.$$

That there is such a vector can be seen by evaluating the above equality with the canonical basis. That it is unique can be seen in the same way. Now your result follows easily.

Answer (score 1):

$u\cdot(v\times w)$ is the determinant of the matrix whose columns are $u$, $v$ and $w$. (This can be used as a *definition* for the cross product).

The identity now follows from the usual determinant rules for permuting rows/columns.